# jQuery .delay() and .fadeIn() to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

```
        $(document).ready(function(){$(".wooo").bloooming_shop();$("body").append('<div id="panel"><div id="panelcontent"></div><div class="panelbutton" id="hidepanel" style="display: none;"><a><font class="cartfont2">hide cart</font></a></div></div><div id="showpanel" class="panelbutton" style="display: visible;"><a><font class="cartfont">shopping cart</font></a></div><div id="btntarget"></div>');$("#panelcontent").hide();$.ajax({type:"GET",url:"/wooo/cart.php",async:false,dataType:"html",success:function(a){$("#panelcontent").html(a)}});
```

I'm sorry it's minified, lol..

I tried both suggestions but it didn't work. I'm not at all certain that I followed instructions perfectly.

Comment: To what part of this code you want to add a delay effe;

Comment: Oh sorry, I want to delay the cart's loading. I'd like the page to load, and then after a couple seconds, the cart finally shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
function docReady() {  
    $('.wooo').bloooming_shop();

    $('body').append('<div id="panel"><div id="panelcontent"></div><div class="panelbutton" id="hidepanel" style="display: none;"><a><font class="cartfont2">hide cart</font></a></div></div><div id="showpanel" class="panelbutton" style="display: visible;"><a><font class="cartfont">shopping cart</font></a></div><div id="btntarget"></div>');
    $('#panelcontent').hide();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/wooo/cart.php",
        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
            $('#panelcontent').html(html);
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout("docReady()", 3333);
    $('#panelcontent').fadeIn(3333);
});
```

Comment: Alright here it is again: (Jesus I'm still trying to figure out how to post things)

Comment: OK I edited my original post at the top. LOL. Forget jquery, I'm learning how to post on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$('#panelcontent').html(html).delay(3333).fadeIn(3333);
```

inside the AJAX success handler?

Comment: OK, I went to try this and noticed that the minified version of this script is slightly different, so I'll have to re-post this.

Comment: I don't see any difference. What changed exactly?

Comment: So in the minified version you wrote this:
success:function(a){$("#panelcontent").html(a).delay(333).fadeIn(333);}
Is that right?

Comment: Hmmm, alright can you paste the code that you have now with the additions above? Also I hope you have noticed that there is a missing semicolon in the code you posted, in the success function.

Comment: You mean "success:function(a)" should really be "success:function(a);"  ...?

Answer (score 0):

Sice you have jquery, can you wrap the fadeIn in a setTimeout in the jQuery(document).ready?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('#panelcontent').html(html).fadeIn(3333);
   }, 3333);
});
```